# How to determine the type of node

Tags: javascript, jstree

We have a JSTree that can have different types of nodes and I have to create a custom menu for each one.

I've reached this point:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialization function for JTree. We can not mve this in a different file, because Genshi placeholders won't be replaced there.             
    $(function () {
        $("#tree4").jstree({ 
            contextmenu: {
                "items" : createDefaultMenu
        },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
            "json_data": {"ajax": { url: "/project/readjsonstructure/${project.id}",
                                    success: function (d) { return eval(d); }
                                   }}
            });
        });

    function createDefaultMenu(obj)
    {   
        return { 
            create: false, 
            rename: false, 
            remove: false, 
            ccp: false, 
            launch_viewer: {
                        label: "Launch viewer",
                        action: function (obj) { 
                                alert('Should launch here.')
                                               },
                        seperator_after: false,
                        seperator_before: false
                    }
            }            
    }
</script>
```

Now from what I've read around obj should contain the currently clicked node in the JSTree  (correct me if I'm wrong). But now how do I find out what kind of node this is? The readjsonstructure returns a:

```
encoder = JSONEncoder()
return encoder.iterencode(result)
```

Where JSONEncoder is from simplejson and result is a dictionary that has the structure:

```
{ data: {
    title: "root",
        icon: "/static/style/nodes/nodeRoot.png"},
    state:"open", 
    attr:{id:"projectID"}, 
    children: [ data { .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question which is quite old but maybe my information can still be valueable for someone else.

I think this blog entry has valueable information for this question: [jsTree: different contextmenu actions for different nodes](https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=364).

The following lines show how you can grab the type of a node by identifying the classes of the node:

```
   var items = {};
   if ($(node).hasClass("jstree-closed")) {
       //build the items object like you want it
       items = "delete" : {
          "label" : "Delete File",
          "action" : function () { ... }
       };
   }
```

The given code snippet only adds the delete function to the context menu if the specific node is closed (hence has the "jstree-closed"-class in its classlist).

Actually this is a quite dirty way as the jsTree-API allows you to directly ask it for a node's state ([jsTree API](http://www.jstree.com/api)).
The question is, what criteria you want to use to apply a certain contextmenu to a node. Some possibilities are:

- Is the node enabled or disabled? [jsTree isDisabled()](http://www.jstree.com/api#/?f=is_disabled%28obj%29)
- Does the node have children or not? [jsTree isParent()](http://www.jstree.com/api#/?f=is_parent%28obj%29)
- Is the node closed or opened? [jsTree isOpen()](http://www.jstree.com/api#/?f=is_open%28obj%29)

You can use those API-calls like follows:

```
$('#treeId').jstree().is_disabled(node);
```

The node is the jQuery-Object, which you either receive by using `$('#nodeId')` or you use the parameter of your `function createDefaultMenu(obj)`. Hence you can identify whether a node is enabled or disabled like this:

```
var node = $('#nodeId')
$('#treeId').jstree().is_disabled(node);
```

I hope this helps someone who stumbles across it. If I made mistakes, let me know.